# ControlValueAccessor with multiple formControl in child component

Tags: angular

I have multiple formcontrols in the child component, how to apply validators in the child component, So that original form will become invalid. It would be ideal to implement it with ControlValueAccessor but want to start with simple @input form group.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `

  <h1>Child</h1>
  <div [formGroup]="childForm">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
    <input formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
  `
})

export class Child {
  @Input()
  childForm: FormGroup;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/K1xAak4tlUKtZmOV1CAQ

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know why the question was down voted, but I feel it may be helpful to other So I am posting the answer.
After multiple attempts to bind child's formgroup I was able to successfully bind value

```js
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `

  <h1>Child</h1>
  <div [formGroup]="name">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
    <input formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: Child, multi: true}
  ]
})

export class Child implements ControlValueAccessor {
  name: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = fb.group({
      firstName:[''],
      lastName: ['']
    });
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if(value) {
        this.name.setValue(value);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this.name.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ldhPf7LTFVtTFHe9zfAj?p=preview

Answer (score 10):

At first, this helped me a lot, but then I found out, that we're over-complicating things. We do not have to build our own formControl, we can just pass the formGroup to our child component.
In the parent component, instead of

```js
this.form = fb.group({
  name:['Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'],
  username: [{firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last'}],
  email:['My Email']  
});
```

we initialize username as a FormGroup instead of a control:

```js
this.form = fb.group({
  name:['Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'],
  username: fb.group({
   firstName: ['First'],
   lastName: ['Last']
  }),
  email:['My Email']
});
```

In the child component we need a Input Property for the FormGroup

```js
@Input()
usernameGroup: FormGroup;
```

In the child template:

```html
<div [formGroup]="usernameGroup">
   <input formControlName="firstName">
   <input formControlName="lastName">
</div>
```

and then in the parent template:

```html
<my-child [usernameGroup]="form.controls.username"></my-child>
```

For more information, check out this post: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Building your own formControl is really an overkill here, for more information about that, have a look here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Do you know how one could use a child form inside and ngFor? The scotch.io tutorial show how to add to an array but I need to use a nested form inside an ngFor. Let's say I have an array of items and I need to add a field to each item and then aggregate all those values back to the main form.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do can be achieved more easily without implementing ControlValueAccessor.
Instead, you can simply set the viewProviders in the child component to use the existing parent NgForm as the ControlContainer.

Then, there's no need to pass the form/formGroup as an input parameter to the child component as the form controls will automatically be part of the parent's form.

child.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
})
export class Child {
    @Input() firstName;
    @Input() lastName;
}
```

child.component.html:

```html
<h1>Child</h1>
<div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstname">
    <input [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="lastname">
</div>
```

parent.component.html:

```html
<form #personalForm="ngForm" name="personalForm">
    <child [firstName]="firstName" [lastName]="lastName"></child>
</form>
```

Comment: this is the only correct answer !