# Designing complex UI using reactive forms angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

[image: Screen Layout]

I am trying to develop screen similar to above image,
Loaded first time UI will look like above, when user clicks ADD then 4 new input fields will be added to new page. So basically below part is paginated user can go next page or back to previous.

mainscreencomponent

```
this.mainform = this._formbuilder.group({
company:[''],
charges: this._formbuilder.array([])
})
```

charges is a model class with two properties,

```
class charges {
type1;
type2;
}
```

in maincomponent html

```
<div [formgroup]="mainform">
.. 
<chargesscreen [chargesdata]="data"></chargesscreen>
</div>
```

data is array of charges objects. I have just passed 4 empty objects in array.

chargesscreen component -- this is where it iterates over the charges array

@Input chargesdata;

chargesscreen.html

```
<div formArrayName="chargesdata" *ngFor"let item of chargesdata.controls; let i = index">
<div [formgroupname]="i">
//displayed components
</div>
</div>
```

controls are displayed but in console i am getting an error,
formArrayName must be used with parent form directive

and also i would like to know the approach of handling pagination, when i click on add new 4 rows will be displayed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can't use form name directives through nested components, they all have to be in the same component. if you want to use nested components, you need to use `formGroup` or `formControl` directives. your casing is also wrong

Comment: your naming doesn't match, you have `mainform` and on the template `main`. what is `chargesdata`, where does it come from? how is it generated, what type of data does it have? what is `mainform`  for?

Comment: @bryan60 you actually can, but you'd need a view provider on the nested template.

Comment: @Bargros I don't believe that's correct unless they've changed something in V9.  You can implement `ControlValueAccessor` and provide `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` to make form name directives work ON your components, but I don't know of anyway you can make them work INSIDE sub components.

Comment: @Bargros I have updated form to mainform.. chargesdata is array of charges class. So data is formarray having array of empty object, initially 4 objects in array.

Comment: @bryan60 is right, unless you're on angular 9, you'll need a `ControlValueAccesor` to access your charges formarray from a nested component in a similar fashion to the following `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513450/controlvalueaccessor-with-multiple-formcontrol-in-child-component`